# Generating a Rank2Type within a Monad

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types

So I superfically understand Rank2Types, but when I try the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Machine

f :: IO (Process a a)
f = return . auto $ id
```

GHC coughs out

```
Couldn't match type `MachineT m0 (Is a0) a0'
              with `forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => MachineT m (Is a) a'
Expected type: IO (Process a a)
  Actual type: IO (MachineT m0 (Is a0) a0)
In the expression: return . auto $ id
In an equation for `f': f = return . auto $ id
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So as far as I can see, GHC won't allow me to put a forall in a Monad. Is there a principled, quantification logic reason for this, or is this simply a limitation of GHC? Or am I simply doing something silly?

Comment: Just adding the `ImpredicativeTypes` pragma isn't sufficient to get GHC to infer impredicative types.  You need to actually annotate the impredicative types. This is such a huge pain, it's more or less never done.

Comment: Also beware of `.` and other seemingly innocent functions when dealing with very polymorphic types. GHC has a nasty habit of generating from type variables with them and ruining your perfectly polymorphic types

Comment: So kosmikus answered my question, but I should add something about machines: In understanding how terrible the types of the functions I'm trying to write would have to be, I dug into the machines library to see how awful the type signatures were, and found none. The point is, as they try to make clear, is that one should construct a machine/process out of a plan, rather than attempting to do so directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your particular example can be made to work as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Machine

f = (return :: (forall a. Process a a) -> IO (forall a. Process a a)) (auto id)
```

As Carl says, you have to annotate functions that you want to use impredicatively, such as `return` here. Even then, working with impredicative types in GHC is somewhat fragile. I wouldn't recommend it. The reasons for the restrictions are simply that it's tricky to perform type inference in the presence of impredicative types, and additionally, Haskell's surface language has no proper syntax to specify the type at which you want to instantiate a polymorphic function.

A common workaround is to wrap stuff up in a `newtype`:

```
data PolyProcess = PP (forall a. Process a a)

f' :: IO PolyProcess
f' = return $ PP $ auto $ id
```